# Save rating in database

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using a jQuery plugin to get a rating per post I made on a PHP-driven website.

The plugin I use is called Raty and can be found [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/raty).

I'm wondering how I can save this rating, because I can click on the stars and then I get a 5 star rating, but if I refresh the page, the rating is gone.

So I should save it somehow.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following for the click event: (sample code)

```
$('#click').raty({
    click: function(score, evt) {
          $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '/SaveMyRating.php',
           data: {'score':score},
          success: function(data){ alert('Your rating was saved'); }         
         });

    }
});
```

SaveMyRating.php should be the php script that will receive the score submitted and save it (file or database, etc).

Comment: You have to remember to read this value from your database or a cookie or some kind of persistent data for it to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

firstly you should create a table for this in your database.

and after you click on the stars, send (by using Ajax) the rate information to your server machine and insert it into your table.

Comment: I already have a table called posts and there I have a field called rating.
So i just have to add the rating to that? And after a refresh I need to do a call to my database to get the rating and put that into the stars?

Comment: Yes your logic is correct. Ajax plays an important role here. It's not difficult to do this work by using jQuery, I bet.

Comment: Okay, that gets me to the other problem.
Coding all of this, haha!
Going to search for it.
Thanks already ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use ajax here to send the latest rating( an integer ) along with other necessary details to a php page. And then save the rating to the database.

```
// rate.php - the php page where you will insert rating.

$('#rate').raty({
    click: function(score) {
    var id = // get the id of the object for which the rating is done
        $.post('rate.php', {score:score,id:id}, function(data) {
         // data is a variable that may or may not be 
             returned from the rate.php page

            });

    }
});
```